# Python run binary and intercept file writes (using subprocess)

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a simple command-line utility which produces output both on the console and the filesystem. While I know very well how to capture the console output, I am not aware how can I also intercept the file - for which I know the filename in advance.

I would like to keep the execution "in memory" without touching the filesystem as I immediately parse and delete the file created and this creates an unnecessary bottleneck (especially when I need to run the little tool millions of times).

So, to sum up, I am trying to achieve following:

1. Run a binary using python's [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)
2. Capture both the tool's output AND contents of a file it creates (in current working directory with in-advance known name)
3. Ideally, run it all without touching the filesystem.

Comment: Doubt you can do this portably. Which OS(es) do you need to support?

Comment: Linux only is sufficient

Comment: Do you have control over the file name? Note that /tmp can be set up to be entirely memory-based (if it's not already.)

Comment: Yes, I do - however I am not sure how the app handles relative directories, it gets some identifier and creates bunch of files with different suffixes starting with the identifier.. will probably stick to mkfifo for the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only need to support Linux, one possibility is to use named pipes. The idea is to pre-create the output file as a named pipe, and have your process read the tool's output from the pipe.

See, for example, [Introduction to Named Pipes](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2156).

The Python API is [`os.mkfifo()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkfifo).